2D Physics inconsistent across platforms
I want to create a black hole like gravity pull effect in Unity2D, and used that code for this:
using UnityEngine;

public class Attractor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private Rigidbody2D playerBody;
    public float influenceRange;
    public float intensity;

    void Start()
    {
        playerBody = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position);
        
        if (distanceToPlayer <= influenceRange)
        {
            Vector2 pullForce = (player.position - transform.position).normalized * intensity;
            playerBody.AddForce(pullForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
}

Intensity is set to 5 and influenceRange to 4.
All references are set up correctly.
In the Unity Editor the pull effect seems much stronger than on android though.
Pull Effect on android:

I can't show pull effect in the editor because I'm not home now, but there the ball flies through the sky and gets attracted much stronger.
Any help is appreciated!

Try putting physics effects in FixedUpdate instead of in Update so they're not impacted by differences in rendering framerate.

Are you looking for How to limit framerate in Unity?

I have found a much more customizable and easy solution for this. I have just added a point effector 2d to the gameobject along with a circle collider with isTrigger and usedByEffector boxes checked.
